# git says my this message " rewrite wordpress/wp-content/themes/musik/images/mic.png (93%)"

Tags: git

I changed an image in my repository, added it and commited, but git says me this message

> rewrite wordpress/wp-content/themes/musik/images/mic.png (93%)

What shall I do?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing.  That's git telling you that between the old image and the new one, a comparison showed it was 93% different (hence 7% the same) so that the user interface calls it a "rewrite" rather than a "small change".